# Cant get data from Create robot - Error reading from SCI port ttyUSB0

Tags: ros, turtlebot, create-robot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

in the turtlebot-dashboard all the sensors are Stale apart from the Laptop battery one, and when I do `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` I get the code below. Weird thing is it worked perfectly yesterday; then I played with Kinect drivers and then it stopped working. So I did a fresh ubuntu install on the turtlebot laptop but I still get the same!

Turtlebot is on and light is green by the way so there is plenty of power. I've also checked `/etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.conf` and it has read and write rules (666). I also checked dmesg and the turtlebot is on ttyUSB0. I can also see the leds on the irobot cable light up in both directions so there is traffic.

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.15:49038/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /use_sim_time
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used
 * /robot/name
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/type
 * /turtlebot_node/update_rate
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/timeout
 * /rosdistro
 * /robot_description
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/base_path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq
 * /app_manager/interface_master
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/startswith
 * /rosversion
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/pub_rate
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/startswith
 * /turtlebot_node/bonus
 * /robot/type
 * /robot_pose_ekf/publish_tf

NODES
  /
    appmaster (app_manager/appmaster)
    app_manager (app_manager/app_manager)
    turtlebot_node (turtlebot_node/turtlebot_node.py)
    turtlebot_laptop_battery (turtlebot_node/laptop_battery.py)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.15:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[appmaster-1]: started with pid [14445]
process[app_manager-2]: started with pid [14446]
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [14447]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-4]: started with pid [14448]
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [14449]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-6]: started with pid [14450]
process[robot_pose_ekf-7]: started with pid [14451]
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method XmlRpcNode.run of <roslib.xmlrpc.XmlRpcNode object at 0xf851d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/xmlrpc.py", line 194, in run
    self._run()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/xmlrpc.py", line 217, in _run
    self.server = ThreadingXMLRPCServer((bind_address, port), log_requests)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/xmlrpc.py", line 97, in __init__
    SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self, addr, SilenceableXMLRPCRequestHandler, log_requests)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 539, in __init__
    SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, addr, requestHandler, bind_and_activate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.211220] Starting app manager for turtlebot
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.301508] Waiting for foreign master [http://localhost:11312] to come up...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.312440] Foreign master is available
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.361951] Registering (/turtlebot/app_list,http://192.168.1.15:47152/) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.400345] Registering (/turtlebot/application/app_status,http://192.168.1.15:47152/) on master http://localhost:11312
turtlebot_apps.installed
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.445143] Registering service (/turtlebot/list_apps,rosrpc://192.168.1.15:53187) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.477154] Registering service (/turtlebot/start_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.15:53187) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529211.500983] Registering service (/turtlebot/stop_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.15:53187) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529214.721543] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529214.722394] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529214.723121] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529214.724031] has gyro: True
shutdown request: new node registered with same name
Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/cff0e8a6-1a26-11e1-ad40-e0b9a530fab3/turtlebot_node-3*.log
respawning...
[turtlebot_node-3] restarting process
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [14851]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529225.099602] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529225.100670] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529225.101445] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1322529225.102162] has gyro: True
Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
```

Here is the turtelbot_node-3.log file:

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:50,999: init_node, name[/turtlebot_node], pid[3131]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,052: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,055: Started XML-RPC server [http://turtlebot-laptop:34856/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,055: ROS Slave URI: [http://turtlebot-laptop:34856/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,056: _ready: http://turtlebot-laptop:34856/
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,060: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,060: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,157: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,158: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,175: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,182: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,237: serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,238: update_rate: 30.0
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,239: drive mode: twist
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:51,240: has gyro: True
[root][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:53,818: sending control opcodes.
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:57,307: external shutdown request from [/master]: new node registered with same name
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:57,308: signal_shutdown [external shutdown request from [/master]: [new node registered with same name]]
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:27:57,375: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.client][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,488: init_node, name[/turtlebot_node], pid[3570]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,490: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,492: Started XML-RPC server [http://turtlebot-laptop:48724/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,493: ROS Slave URI: [http://turtlebot-laptop:48724/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,493: _ready: http://turtlebot-laptop:48724/
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,497: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,498: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,594: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,595: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,612: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,619: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,694: serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,695: update_rate: 30.0
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,697: drive mode: twist
[rosout][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:01,698: has gyro: True
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:03,987: signal_shutdown [signal-2]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:04,086: signal-2
[root][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:04,916: sending control opcodes.
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-11-29 13:28:06,422: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12127/cant-get-data-from-create-robot---error-reading-from-sci-port-ttyusb0/) by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on 2011-11-28**:
I did sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0 but still no luck :-(

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-28**:
Try setting the permissions to ttyUSB* and check it this works.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-28**:
I presume It should be either the permissions or the hardware. If not lets wait for some one to share their thoughts.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-28**:
This one might help http://answers.ros.org/question/1736/turtlebot-disconnects-when-additional-devttyusb

**Comment by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on 2011-11-28**:
I ran dmesg and it confirmed that the turtlebot is connected to ttyUSB0, which is the one the minimal.launch is looking for it; so I reckon it should be ok 'usb 2-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0'

**Comment by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on 2011-11-28**:
Thanks I've edited the question

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-28**:
Could you post the information in the log file mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

turned out my cable was faulty...

---

Originally posted by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) with karma: 58 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tgilmour](https://answers.ros.org/users/25907/tgilmour/) on 2016-02-10**:
How did you discover that your cable was faulty?